# Applying complex gradients in logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient

[image]

I am trying to trace this logo but i am not getting how can apply this gradient and how to apply depth using lines. I tried by drawing lines and gradient stoke around it but this  was not helpful for me. can anyone help to apply this color scheme and depth?
(Downside picture is my effort but not yet filled with color)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method.

1. Draw the lines over the raster logo, making sure to overlap some of the lines
2. Use the Shape Builder tool to make solid pieces you can fill, and to delete the pieces and lines that aren't required.
3. Fill the separate pieces with gradients as required
4. Finally add a white stroke with "Width Profile 1" along the three bottom segments, and reduce its opacity a little.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: Got it Thank you very much. :)